# Laravel:Can't drop foreign key even using 'dropForeign' method

Tags: laravel

I'm about to refresh my migration. But `php artisan migrate:refresh` command is not working.
It shows the following error:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1091 Can't DROP 'classes_userid_foreign'; check
>   that column/key   exists (SQL: alter table `classes` drop foreign key
>   `classes_userid_foreign`)
>
> [PDOException]   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>   1091 Can't DROP 'classes_userid_foreign'; check that column/key
>   exists

I even used the `dropForeign` but its not working for me.

I'm showing my `migration` file

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('userId')->unsigned();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('code')->unique();
        $table->integer('capacity')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('tagId')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('userId')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('classes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->dropForeign(['userId']);
    });
    Schema::drop('classes');
}
```

How to fix this problem ?

Comment: Did you check the table and verify the foreign key is there?

Answer (score 1):

Most times when you run migrations in laravel (whether up or down), and an error occurs along the line, the transaction may have completed partially without registering it in the migrations table.

If this is the case, or you will like to drop tables whether or not there really exists a foreign key, then you should consider disabling foreign key checks like so:

```
public function down()
{
    Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::drop('classes');
    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
}
```

Comment: I have `Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint::dropForeign() should not be called statically` error, I use @Emeke solution and it works… only if we drop the table. Thanks